# Terraform AWS Provider - import aws_api_gateway_account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

When importing aws_api_gateway_account it is not matching the output of “aws apigateway get-account”

The cloudwatchRoleArn is not imported properly. I am using Terraform 1.2.2 and aws provider 4.18.0.

I am importing according to the documentation [Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_account#import)

Ex:

```
terraform import aws_api_gateway_account.rest_api_account api-gateway-account
```

Comment: What is the generated plan after import? It is not guaranteed (and also unlikely) that your current config will match the actual resource exactly.

Comment: The plan after import shows 1 change to the existing account resource. the change the addition of the cloudwatch_role_arn attribute. This attribute and correct value are already set in AWS, if I get the account information via CLI I can see the cloudwatch_role_arn value is already set.